# UITableView maintain scroll position after device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do we maintain current scrolling position in a table view when device is rotated?

I've tried this solution but it doesn't work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779728/12114641

Comment: If you want help, you need to do more than link to an answer and say *"it doesn't work"*. Show your code, and explain what's *not working*. It would also be useful to explain what you've ***tried*** to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt fix. You have to save the scroll position (row) before rotation and then scroll to that row after rotation.

In `viewWillLayoutSubviews` save row and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` call scroll to the saved row.